# Spring runtime use swap bean class

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

```
@Component
@Qualifier("SUCCESS")
public class RandomServiceSuccess implements RandomService{
    public String doStuff(){
       return "success";
   }
}

@Component
@Qualifier("ERROR")
public class RandomServiceError implements RandomService{
    public String doStuff(){
       throw new Exception();
   }
}
```

the calling code

```
 @Controller
    public class RandomConroller {
        @Autowired 
        private RandomService service;
        public String do(){
           service.doStuff();
       }
    }
```

What I need to do here is to have them swapped based on a value can be retrieved from some custom http header from a http request. Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you inject both and just use the one you need?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis how exactly to swap the implementation at runtime? They are injected cause Spring auto-scan and discovers them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm totally agree with Sotirios Delimanolis that you need to inject all the implementations and choose one of them at runtime.

If you have many implementations of `RandomService` and don't want to clutter `RandomController` with selection logic, then you can make `RandomService` implementations responsible for selection, as follows:

```
public interface RandomService{
    public boolean supports(String headerValue);
    public String doStuff();
}

@Controller
public class RandomConroller {
    @Autowired List<RandomService> services;

    public String do(@RequestHeader("someHeader") String headerValue){
        for (RandomService service: services) {
            if (service.supports(headerValue)) {
                 return service.doStuff();
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No suitable implementation");
    }
}
```

If you want to define priorities for different implementations, you may use [`Ordered`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/Ordered.html) and put the injected implementations into a `TreeSet` with `OrderComparator`.

Comment: +1 Note that this pattern is how Spring resolves arguments to pass to your handler methods and how it resolves the returned value of those methods. Alternatively, you can implement a `RandomServiceProvider` that performs the logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can just inject both and use the one you need.

```
@Inject
private RandomServiceSuccess success;

@Inject
private RandomServiceError error;

...
String value = request.getHeader("some header");
if (value == null || !value.equals("expected")) {
    error.doStuff();
} else {
    success.doStuff();
}
```

Comment: I have over 10 different implementations. I am looking for a solution that only need to inject  the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Qualifier should be used to specify which instance of the interface you want injected in the field after specifying different IDs for each one. Following @Soritios' advice you could do something like:

```
@Component("SUCCESS")
public class RandomServiceSuccess implements RandomService{
    public String doStuff(){
       return "success";
   }
}

@Component("ERROR")
public class RandomServiceError implements RandomService{
    public String doStuff(){
       throw new Exception();
   }
}


@Component
public class MyBean{
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("SUCCESS")
    private RandomService successService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ERROR")
    private RandomService successService;

    ....
    if(...)
}
```

...or you could obtain just the instance you want from the application context based on your parameter:

```
@Controller
public class RandomConroller {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public String do(){
        String myService = decideWhatSericeToInvokeBasedOnHttpParameter();

        // at this point myService should be either "ERROR" or "SUCCESS"
        RandomService myService = applicationContext.getBean(myService);

        service.doStuff();
   }
}
```